# Run QProcess with and without a GUI

Tags: qt, user-interface

I have been playing with QProcess as a way to start computationally intensive tasks that way continue after the GUI that created them has been closed. I was now wondering whether I could improve on this so that not too many jobs can be started.

Say I have 20 available cores. User 1 starts a computation that is broken into 30 processes and exits the GUI. At the moment I'm using bash to control all of this so the GUI only really executes a bash script which counts the number of processes running. The whole workflow gets rather messy if another user logs in and starts another large job in the meantime so currently it refuses to submit if the script is already running. Also, there is no way to use the GUI to monitor the processes as they are now being run by bash.

Ideally I would like to improve the flow so that user 1 submits their processes. A separate background process manages the starting of the individual compute tasks - all of which are now QProcesses. Where I am getting stuck is if another user logs in. As opposed to 'please try again later' I would like to pick up the existing managing QProcesses and append any new jobs to that queue. Is this something I can do with QProcess and D-bus? If so what would be a good design for such a process.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking requires two programs; a Gui client and a Server application.

The logged-on users interact with a Gui client interface, to launch and organise processes. The Gui client creates messages and sends them to the server application, which responds by creating and managing processes with QProcess. So the Gui client is simply an interface to the server application.

Of-course, you need the Gui applications and the server application to communicate with each other. While there are multiple methods of interprocess communication available, Qt has QLocalServer and QLocalSocket, which can be used by the server and client applications respectively.